# Understanding how multiselection of TTreeView items in Delphi 7 works

Tags: delphi, treeview, delphi-7, multi-select

Can some one explain me, how `MultiSelectStyle`, `Selected` and `Selected.Count` properties works for `TTreeView` in Delphi 7? I've been away Delphi coding for years and unless someone points me out, what do I miss, I see absolutely no logic behind that.

To the point. I have a routine that fills `TTreeView` with contents of selected folder. It uses recurence, so each folder is represented as node with children -- it's subfolders and files. User can select multi items on a tree, because `MultiSelect` is set to `True`. In `MultiSelectStyle` group I've set all four child properties to `True` as well (maybe that was a mistake).

As a debug of my program (which works exactly opposite, I would expect) I have this code:

```
ShowMessage(IntToStr(tvShell.Selected.Count) + ' selected');

for i := 0 to (tvShell.Selected.Count - 1) do
begin
    ShowMessage(tvShell.Selected.Item[i].Text);
end;
```

So I run my program and select any folder. Tree renders and I see:

- root node with full path of selected folder as `Text` and with six children, as selected folder contains six subfolders and no files,
- these six subfolders contains only files, so six children of root node contains respectful number of children, for example -- first contains 44 (files or items) and last contains 9 (items or files).

Using `Ctrl` and mouse, I select first (44 files) and last (9 files) tree node (children of root node) and hit the button that executes above mentioned debug code.

[image: Example tree contents]

What do I expect? I see **two items selected**. Since `msVisibleOnly` is set to `True` among `MultiSelectStyle`, I expect to have `tvShell.Selected.Count` set to `2` and see three messages.

What do I get? First message says that I have... **nine items selected** and when I continue, I'm getting additional nine messages, showing me *contents of last folder* (tree children). The funniest part is that among `tvShell.Selected` *there are no sign of those two, that are actually selected* by me! WTF?

Non-sense continues...

I repeat all these steps, but this time I'm selecting (clicking) on last folder (children) and with `Ctrl` button pressed, I'm clicking on first folder (root's children). As a human I again see, that I have **two items selected**. When looking at this tree I visually see no difference in selection. But Delphi does.

When executing debug code, this time I'm getting information that there are **fourty four items selected** and I'm getting 44 additional message boxes showing me contents of first folder. Completely confused, I'm clicking `+` next to first and last folder to see, if there are any items selected inside, but no (since `msVisibleOnly` is set to `True`).

I see, how does it work (always claiming that children of last time clicked item are all among selected items), but I don't understand it. Where is the logic behind this, if any? How this can be useful, if results from the code does not reflect the reality?

Sorry, for hard tongue, but this is complete stupidity for me. Since I don't code in Delphi (I actually hate that language for more things like that) I don't look for an enlightenment or explanation, why this works like it works (although, if someone have some spare time, I'll be more than happy to read it).

But I would truly be happy, if someone could explain me, what magic do I have to do in code and among `TTreeView` properties, to get from code, what is truly selected, not the Delphi's false interpretation of reality. If I see two items selected, I want `tvShell.Selected.Count` to be set to 2 and I want `tvShell.Selected` contain exactly two items -- both, that I have selected. Nothing more, nothing less.

Sorry, that this question is such long, but I had to react after frustration I've got, when finding (again, after years), that Delphi is really a weird language.

Comment: Wild shot: This tutorial by Andre v.d. Merwe helped me a a lot in the past: http://users.iafrica.com/d/da/dart/zen/Articles/TTreeView/TTreeView_Main.html Maybe there's stuff in there for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code displays the value of

```
tvShell.Selected.Count
```

That's the number of nodes that are direct children of `tvShell.Selected`. Remember that `tvShell.Selected` is just a single node.

You probably meant to use

```
tvShell.SelectionCount
```

And you then display

```
tvShell.Selected.Item[i].Text
```

These are the captions of the direct children of `tvShell.Selected`.

If you want to iterate through all selected nodes then you can do it like this:

```
for i := 0 to tvShell.SelectionCount-1 do
  DoSomething(tvShell.Selections[i]);
```

---

I recommend reading the online help when you are faced with situations like this. Particularly for Delphi 7 the documentation is very clear. For `Selected` the documentation states:

> Specifies the selected node in the tree view.
>
> **property** Selected: TTreeNode;
>
> **Description**
>
> Read Selected to access the selected node of the tree view. If there
>   is no selected node, the value of Selected is nil.
>
> .....
>
> If the MultiSelect property is True and the MultiSelectStyle property
>   includes msControlSelect, then Selected returns the last node clicked
>   on, even if that click deselected the node. For a current selection
>   status when MultiSelect is True, refer to the Selections property.

And then when you follow on to the documentation for `Count` it says:

> Indicates the number of direct descendants of a tree node.
>
> **property** Count: Integer;
>
> **Description**
>
> Use Count to determine how many child nodes belong to a tree node.
>   Count includes only immediate children, and not their descendants.
>   Count can be useful when iterating through the children of a tree
>   node.

In other words, the documentation tells you just the same as I have told you.

Comment: Perfect answer -- thank you! All I can say, is that I'm using Windows 7 and old .hlp file that ships with my Delphi 7 works just less poorly. That's why I wasn't able to figure out everything from that source. Thanks again!

Comment: You need to install the MS update that lets you view .hlp files on Win 7. I did this answer on Win 7!